# How to keep an FFmpeg stream running when terminal gets closed; nohup not working

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, streaming

I built a birdbox including a Raspberry Pi + Raspberry Pi Camera. It is connected via Wi-Fi to my router and I want it to stream to my YouTube channel.

The projects section of `raspberrypi.org` suggests to use the following command line:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 4000000 -g 50 | ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key goes here>
```

This works nearly perfect, as long as I don't close my terminal session. How do I start streaming without having to keep the terminal session active?

I read about `nohup <command line> &` but that didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `nohup &` "didn't work"? Please explain exactly what you did and what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Detach Your SSH Session for the Stream to Continue
The `raspivid` command above initiates a stream, but if you’re connecting via SSH, when you disconnect the stream will close. Surely you can’t leave your PC running just for the Pi to keep streaming?

Fortunately, there is an answer: [`screen`](https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html). This is a piece of software you can install that will keep the SSH session running once you disconnect.

Begin by ending the stream (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>), then installing screen:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Wait for it to install, then reboot the Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo reboot
```

Reconnect over SSH, sign in, then enter the command to run screen:

```
screen
```

This basically creates a separate environment for you to run the raspivid command in, one that will persist when you disconnect. Simply run raspivid as above, then when you’re ready to disconnect hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Close the SSH window, and the stream will continue.